# ServerRpc not working in a custom Vaadin Widgetset, why do I get "Widgetset '...' does not contain implementation for '...'?

Tags: gwt, widget, vaadin, rpc

I have a question about the ServerRpc implemetation in Vaadin, I have a simple example project in eclipse with a widgetset:

Here are the classes:

widgetpackage.MarqueeLabel :

```
public class MarqueeLabel extends AbstractComponent {




/**

     * 

     */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



@Override

public MarqueeLabelState getState() {

       return (MarqueeLabelState) super.getState();

    }



@Override

public void setCaption(String caption) {

       getState().text = caption;

    } 




}
```

widgetpackage.WidgetUI:

```
public class WidgetUI extends UI {




@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)

@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = WidgetUI.class, widgetset = "widgetpackage.widgetWidgetset")

public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

    }




@Override

protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        layout.setMargin(true);

        setContent(layout);




        MarqueeLabel label = new MarqueeLabel();

        label.setCaption("Hello I am custom widget!");



        layout.addComponent(label);

    }




}
```

widgetpackage.client.MarqeeLabelWidget:

```
public class MarqueeLabelWidget extends Label {




    public MarqueeLabelWidget() {

            final Element el = getElement();

            el.getStyle().setPosition(Position.RELATIVE);



            Timer timer = new Timer() {

                private int left = 0;



                @Override

                public void run() {

                    el.getStyle().setLeft(left, Unit.PX);

                    left++;

                }

            };

            timer.scheduleRepeating(100);

        }



    }

widgetpackage.client.MarqueeLabelState: 

public class MarqueeLabelState extends AbstractComponentState {




/**

     * 

     */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




public String text;



}
```

widgetpackage.client.MarqueeLabelConnector:

```
@Connect(MarqueeLabel.class)

public class MarqueeLabelConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {




/**

     * 

     */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




@Override

public Widget createWidget() {

        return GWT.create(MarqueeLabelWidget.class);

    }



@Override

public MarqueeLabelWidget getWidget() {

        return (MarqueeLabelWidget) super.getWidget();

    }



@Override

public MarqueeLabelState getState() {

        return (MarqueeLabelState) super.getState();

    }



    @Override

    public void onStateChanged(StateChangeEvent e) {

            super.onStateChanged(e);

            getWidget().setText(getState().text);

        }



    }
```

the WidgetWidgetset.gwt.xml is located in the widgetpackage package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module>

    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />

</module>
```

When I build the widgetset and 'Run on server' everything works fine, but then when I add this ServerRpc implementation, like this:

1) Add the widgetpackage.MarqueeLabelServerRpc interface (widgetpackage, where MarqueeLabel server component is located):

```
 public interface MarqueeLabelServerRpc extends ServerRpc {

      public void clicked();

    }
```

2) Add this lines to the widgetpackage.client.MarqueeLabelConnector:

```
public class MarqueeLabelConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {

  private MarqueeLabelServerRpc rpc = RpcProxy.create(
      MarqueeLabelServerRpc.class, this);

  public MarqueeLabelConnector() {
    getWidget().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        rpc.clicked(); // server's call
      }
    });
  }

  // ...

}
```

3) And this constructor to the widgetpackage.MarqueeLabel:
public class MarqueeLabel extends AbstractComponent {

```
  public MarqueeLabel() {
    registerRpc(new MarqueeLabelServerRpc() {
      @Override
      public void clicked() {
        Notification.show("Made a RPC”); 
      }
    });
  }

  // ...

}
```

If I recompile the widgetset and run the project, I get this in the browser:

> Widgetset 'widgetpackage.widgetWidgetset' does not contain
>   implementation for 'widgetpackage.MarqueeLabel'. Check its component
>   connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file
>   and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin
>   add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.

Why when I add the RPC implementation, the widgetset doesn't find the implementation of MarqueeLabel anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved, the problem was that MarqueeLabelServerRpc needed to be inside the widgetpackage.client package and not widgetpackage.